# Best search method for site with 50,000 products?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've got a new site that has a large amount of products listed, built with php and using a mysql database.

We need the search to work like that of other large sites, so for example picking up products with "mountain bike" in the title when searching for "mountain bikes" - using LIKE doesn't do this when just searching on the term entered. I've used AGAINST matching on a smaller site which works fine there but since each word is searched on individually it could bring up a huge number of irrelevant products in this case due to the number in the database.

Can anyone help please with what would be the best method to use for searching on the site?

Comment: When you will use `LIKE 'mountain bike%'` it will produce a hit on `mountain bikes`

Comment: Best search method? Apache Solr. If you want to stick to MySQL only, perhaps a full-text search might be an option (though it will be slower and less precise than Solr, which is based on the godess that Lucene is).

Comment: Isn't full text searching using MATCH AGAINST etc as I'd mentioned? Won't that search each word individually which would then bring up any product with the title including "mountain" or "bike"?

stUrb, I meant LIKE '%mountain bikes%' wouldn't bring up a product titled 'mountain bike' unless there are ways to alter this?

Comment: Note that searching the 'site' and searching the 'database' are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's fulltext boolean search supports cases where you want to search for text that matches  all words, as if you used [boolean AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) between them:

```
WHERE MATCH(product_description) AGAINST ('+mountain +bikes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But this only searches for text that contains both words, the word 'bikes' might occur before 'mountain', or the two words could be separated by other text.

Once the subset of rows has been found, you can further refine it with a non-optimized predicate to search for the exact phrase.  You can hope that the "false positives" don't cause too much extra work.

```
WHERE MATCH(product_description) AGAINST ('+mountain +bikes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND product_description LIKE '%mountain bikes%'
```

You could also use other more flexible text search tools, which have the capability to search for phrases (and many other features that MySQL's fulltext search lacks).

- [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr)
- [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com)

Check out my comparison in my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is that one person's "completely irrelevant" might be another person's "very relevant".

I suggest you use MySQL's `MATCH...AGAINST` and `ORDER BY` to sort results in descending order. Use a `WHERE` clause to ensure you only show results where the match returns a result > 0. That way you will eliminate the least relevant products (those where `MATCH...AGAINST` returns 0) but still show products that are even somewhat relevant.

Answer (score -2):

If your site is well-managed in Google Webmaster tools and is already indexed, you can use a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE).

https://www.google.com/cse/

I've found that using one of these actually improves your indexed results because you catch seo issues while getting the search to work.

I would not recommend this as an overnight solution,  but with a month or two of using it internally,  could be your best bet.

Comment: How is that related? The OP is talking about searching data in a MySQL database -- and **not** a search engine. So, I don't see how GWT would help.

Comment: Google crawls your site, and probably offers better search functions for your site than a standard MySQL search.

Comment: Sorry, it can't be using google as I need to allow the user to change the sort order etc of the results

Comment: CSE? Really? No. I have to agree with Amal. I'm pretty sure we're not talking about search engines.

Comment: Not a fan of Google, but this seems to do what the OP wants.

Comment: You must read the entire context, problem description and answer not by the question title.

Comment: +1 CSE is not useful for every site, but it is great for some.  FWIW, you can do some pretty powerful things with custom filtering and sorting.  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search